# stl: выборка уникальных названий из векторов (найти все вхождения в вектор 1, которых нет в векторе 2)

Tags: c++, vector, файловая-система, stl, find

Подскажите как лучше сделать следующую задачу:

У меня есть 2 списка (вектора) с путями: `filesPathes` и `excludesPathes`. Надо выбрать и записать в новый список (вектор) `includesPathes` только такие пути к файлам, имена которых присутствуют в путях `filesPathes` и отсутствуют в путях `excludesPathes`.

Очень бы хотелось короткое, красивое и быстрое решение :)

Я сделал все через `std::find_if` и библиотеку `<filesystem>`, но получилось, как мне кажется, излишне навороченным :(

```
using strings_t = std::vector<std::string>;

// получить список файлов из папки с файлами для анализа
const strings_t filesPathes = getFilesPathes(folderIn);
const strings_t excludesPathes = getFilesPathes(folderOut);

// выбрать уникальные записи
strings_t includesPathes;

for (const auto &fileIn : filesPathes)
{
    const std::string fileName = std::filesystem::path(fileIn).stem().generic_string();

    const auto res = std::find_if(std::begin(excludesPathes), std::end(excludesPathes), [&fileName](const std::string& path) {
        const std::string fileName2 = std::filesystem::path(path).stem().generic_string();

        return (fileName == fileName2);
    });

    if (res == excludesPathes.cend())
        includesPathes.push_back(fileIn);
}
```

Особенно смущает, что для каждого пути из `filesPathes` надо делать поиск по всему `excludesPathes`, что все таки не очень хорошо.

Думал сделать еще через `std::set<std::string>` куда разместить все имена файлов из `excludesPathes`, по скорости наверное это самый оптимальный вариант, но плодить отдельную сущность (множество) как-то не хочется, поскольку задача относительно одноразовая и небольшая. НО! Из любви к искусству хочется наиболее правильный подход.

Такой вопрос - если взять за основу приведенный код, можно ли его силами stl как-то то еще утрамбовать? Может есть в stl функции, которые и должны делать такие задачи - находить пересечения в массивах?

Comment: [set_difference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать алгоритм set_difference:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using strings_t = std::vector<std::string>;


int main(){

    const strings_t filesPath{"A","B","C"};// = getFilesPaths(folderIn);
    const strings_t excludePath{"B","D"};// = getFilesPaths(folderOut);


    strings_t includePaths;

    std::set_difference(filesPath.begin(), filesPath.end(),
                        excludePath.begin(), excludePath.end(), 
                        std::inserter(includePaths, includePaths.begin()));

    // includePaths: A, C
    return 0;
}
```